# Javascript History.Go default to page if not current site

Tags: javascript, php

I'm using the following history.go in search results with acceptable results cross-browser.  I'd prefer a PHP solution but this filled the needs until I realized a larger issue.

```
<a href="javascript:history.go(-1)">Return To Search Results</a>
```

My only issue is when the viewer comes from a page NOT originating from the search page http://www.domain.com/search/

Is there a way to modify this to use the simple script but if the previous -1 history is NOT the search page URL to redirect to the search page URL if the href is clicked?

Comment: The only information you can get from the history object is length, so perhaps you could use cookies or local storage to create your own "history-feature" instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the php variable `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` will give you the page the current tab / window was on before it got to you.
this value might be empty if someone opened your page directly by typing in the url or by preventing this value to be transmitted to the server.

all in all there is no way to access the browser history at all due to security reasons.

`$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` is all there is that you could make use of. sorry to disappoint you.

btw.. its commonly used in hot linking prevention through out various blogs so people cannot "link" to pictures and files etc.

in your case you just need to figure out if the url equals the search site.